# Using Windows DEL command to secure delete numbered files with the .tmp extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, delete-file

I have a lot of files like `11360.tmp`, `3165.tmp` and many others in subdirectory of my `website`... what I'd like to obtain is delete only files numbered with the extension `.tmp` so for example I have this web structure:

```
www\news\1240\1240.tmp
www\news\1240\topic.tmp
www\news\1240\1240.bot
www\news\1240\1240.php
www\news\1240\1240.bot
www\news\1240\comm.txt
www\news\1240\true.txt

www\news\15640\15640.tmp
www\news\15640\topic.tmp
www\news\15640\15640.bot
www\news\15640\15640.php
www\news\15640\15640.bot
www\news\15640\comm.txt
www\news\15640\true.txt
```

The folder news contains a lot of directories numbered that contain the numbered files `xxxxx.tmp`

I'd like to delete only `xxxxx.tmp` excluding `topic.tmp` and all other files...

`del /S www\news\ *.tmp` excluding `topic.tmp`

How to do? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Batch file below delete the `*.tmp` files *that start with digit*:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set digits=0123456789

for /R "www\news" %%a in (*.tmp) do (
   set name=%%~Na
   for /F %%b in ("!name:~0,1!") do (
      if "!digits:%%b=!" neq "%digits%" del "%%a"
   )
)
```

If this method is not enough for your needs it may be changed by a more precise one, although it would also be slower...

Another method is to delete all *.tmp files excepting "topic.tmp":

```
@echo off
for /R "www\news" %%a in (*.tmp) do (
   if /I "%%~Na" neq "topic" del "%%a"
)
```

Comment: Secure deleted 210 files with only numbers and with extension .tmp. Thanks!!! I'm very very happy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /s /a-d www\news\* ^| findstr "\\[0-9][0-9]*\.[^.]*$"'
) do del "%%F"
```

This will delete all files with a name that consists of digits, followed by an extension. For example, it will delete all of the following:

```
123.ext
123.456
```

It will not delete any of the following:

```
text123.ext
123
123.456.ext
```

The FINDSTR filter can be refined if the above does not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way: it hides the file you want to keep, removes the rest, and unhides the file again

It searches for the file recursively.

```
attrib +h www\news\topic.tmp /s
del /s www\news\*.tmp
attrib -h www\news\topic.tmp /s
```

Comment: www\news\1240\topic.tmp and not www\news\topic.tmp, your trick is useful but attrib sould search in subdir... www\news\1240\1240.tmp
www\news\1240\topic.tmp
www\news\1240\1240.bot
www\news\1240\1240.php
www\news\1240\1240.bot
www\news\1240\comm.txt
www\news\1240\true.txt

www\news\15640\15640.tmp
www\news\15640\topic.tmp
www\news\15640\15640.bot
www\news\15640\15640.php
www\news\15640\15640.bot
www\news\15640\comm.txt
www\news\15640\true.txt